# Is it possible to programmatically stop / start syncing with Skype account?

Tags: android, skype

I want my app to allow the user to stop / start Skype syncing on an Android phone.

I can't find the relevant authority after running `ContentResolver.getSyncAdapterTypes();` and outputting the results to the screen.

My results are:

```
com.android.contacts
com.evernote.evernoteprovider
com.android.email.provider
com.android.email.provider
com.android.gms.plus.action
com.google.android.music.MusicContent
com.android.calendar
com.google.android.apps.plus.content
EsGooglePhotoProvider
com.android.chrome
com.google.android.gms.games
com.google.android.apps.plus.content.EsProvider
com.android.contacts
com.android.contacts
com.google.android.gms.people
com.android.contacts
gmail-ls
com.android.contacts
subscribedfeeds
com.android.contacts
com.google.android.location.reporting
com.google.android.gms.appstate
com.google.android.apps.plus.iu
EsGoogleuProvider
com.android.calendar
```

None of these seem to be related to Skype. Furthermore, Skype is not listed in the '`Settings->Accounts & Sync`' list.

Comment: Perhaps Skype don't use Android Account Manager?

Comment: Hmmmm - it's possible. Anyone out there have definite knowledge on this?